# LAPACK inversion routine strangely mixes up all variables

Tags: fortran, lapack, linear-equation

I'm programming in fortran and trying to use the DGETRI matrix inverter from the Lapack package:

http://www.netlib.org/lapack/explore-html/df/da4/dgetri_8f.html

But very strangely it seems to be messing with all my variables. In this very simple example, my matrix A initialised at the beginning of the program changes as DGETRI is applied, even though DGETRI doesn't involve A…

Can anybody tell me what is going on? Thanks!

```
PROGRAM solvelinear

REAL(8), dimension(2,2)     :: A,Ainv
REAL(8),allocatable         :: work(:)
INTEGER                     :: info,lwork,i
INTEGER,dimension(2)        :: ipiv

info=0
lwork=10000
allocate(work(lwork))
work=0
ipiv=0

A = reshape((/1,-1,3,3/),(/2,2/))
Ainv = reshape((/1,-1,3,3/),(/2,2/))

CALL DGETRI(2,Ainv,2,Ipiv,work,lwork,info)

print*,"A = "
do i=1,2
  print*,A(i,:)
end do

END PROGRAM solve linear
```

This is the output:

```
 A =
   1.0000000000000000        0.0000000000000000
  -1.0000000000000000       0.33333333333333331
```

Comment: Your code is not compilable and doesn't reproduce the problem (with gfortran 4.9.1 and lapack 3.5.0). Additionally, it doesn't calculate the inverse of A, because you forgot to calculate the factorization with zgetrf (which doesn't matter with respect to your specific problem).

Comment: Thanks you. Do you know what's wrong now with my computation of the inverse? (see below).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to compute the LU decomposition before calling DGETRI.
You are using the double version of the routines so the LU has to be computed with `DGETRF` (`ZGETRF` is the complex version).

The following code compiles and returns the correct values

```
PROGRAM solvelinear
implicit none
REAL(8), dimension(3,3)     :: A,Ainv,M,LU
REAL(8),allocatable              :: work(:)
INTEGER                        :: info,lwork
INTEGER,dimension(3)        :: ipiv
INTEGER                        :: i

info=0
lwork=100
allocate(work(lwork))
work=0
ipiv=0

A = reshape((/1,-1,3,3,1,1,1,1,1,1/),(/3,3/))

!-- LU factorisation
LU = A
CALL DGETRF(3,3,LU,3,ipiv,info)

!-- Inversion of matrix A using the LU
Ainv=LU
CALL DGETRI(3,Ainv,3,Ipiv,work,lwork,info)

!-- computation of A^-1 * A to check the inverse
M = matmul(Ainv,A)

print*,"M = "
do i=1,3
  print*,M(i,:)
end do

END PROGRAM solvelinear
```

OUTPUT

```
M = 
1.0000000000000000        0.0000000000000000        0.0000000000000000     
0.0000000000000000        1.0000000000000000       -5.5511151231257827E-017
-4.4408920985006262E-016  -2.2204460492503131E-016   1.0000000000000000
```

By the way, your original code returns the expected unchanged value of A when compiled with gfortran 4.8.2

Comment: Now this looks very strange, because there is no ZGETRF in the question. Only i the deleted invisible post.

Comment: mmm, there was when I answered

Comment: It was in an "answer", which is now deleted. Never mind, just adjust your answer, so that it makes sense why this is the right thing to do.