# Solve very large system of linear equations with Numpy

Tags: python, numpy, algebra

I'm trying to solve a system of equations that is a 1 Million x 1 Million square matrix and one 1 Million solution vector.

To do this, I'm using np.linalg.solve(matrix, answers) but it's taking a very long time.

Is there a way to speed it up?

Thanks @Chris but that doesn't answer the question since I've also tried using the Scipy module and it still takes a very long time to solve. I don't think my computer can hold that much data in RAM

OK for clarity, I've just found out that the name of the matrix that I'm trying to solve is a Hilbert matrix

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Best performance method when solving 7000x7000 linear system with python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59460326/best-performance-method-when-solving-7000x7000-linear-system-with-python)

Comment: How much memory does your computer have? A 1Mx1M matrix should take a few terabytes of RAM.

Comment: 16 Gb, is there any other place in memory where numpy can save the matrix as it solves it? besides RAM?

Comment: Try caching it. Or use numba since you are using numpy. If not, you can try cython or PyPy

Comment: Solving a system of linear equations requires fast access to the whole matrix, so storing the matrix on disk is usually not an option. Since every double precision number occupies 8 bytes, your computer memory could hold about 40,000x40,000 matrix at most. For a 1Mx1M matrix you would probably want at least 12 TB on a single machine or in a cluster.

Answer (score 3):

Please reconsider the need for solving such a HUGE system unless your system is very *sparse*.

Indeed, this is barely possible to store the input/output on a PC storage device: the input dense matrix takes 8 TB with double-precision values and the output will certainly also takes few TB not to mention a temporary data storage is needed to compute the result (at least 8 TB for a dense matrix). Sparse matrices can help a lot if your input matrix is almost full of zeros but you need the matrix to contain >99.95% of zeros so to store it in your RAM.

Furthermore, the time complexity of solving a system is `O(n m min(n,m))` so `O(n^3)` in your case (see: [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3970637/what-is-the-computational-complexity-to-solve-a-system-of-linear-equations)). This means a several billion billions operations. A basic mainstream processor do not exceed 0.5 TFlops. In fact, my relatively good i5-9600KF reach 0.3 TFlops in the LINPACK computationally intensive benchmark. This means the computation will certainly *take a month to compute* assuming is is bounded only by the speed of a mainstream processor. Actually, solving a large system of equations is known to be *memory bound* so it will be much slower in practice because modern RAM are a bottleneck in modern computers (see: [memory wall](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random-access_memory#Memory_wall)). So for a mainstream PC, this should take from from several months to a year assuming the computation can be done in your RAM which is not possible as said before for a dense system. Since high-end SSD are about an order of magnitude slower than the RAM of a good PC, you should expect the computation to take **several years**. Not to mention a 20 TB high-end SSD is *very expensive* and it might be a good idea to consider power outages and OS failure for such a long computational time... Again, sparse matrices can help a lot, but note that solving sparse systems is known to be significantly slower than dense one unless the number of zeros is pretty small.

Such systems are solved on **supercomputers** (or at least large computing clusters), not regular PCs. This requires to use *distributed computing* and tools likes MPI and distributed linear solvers. A whole field of research is working on this topic to make them efficient on large scale systems.

Note that computing *approximations* can be faster, but one should solve the space problem in the first place...

Comment: Thanks for your detailed response, I'm trying to solve this problem as part of a math/computer science problem. I'm starting to come to terms with the fact that brute forcing it might not be the way to go

Answer (score 0):

You could try the formula for the inverse of the Hilbert matrix given on Wikipedia:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert_matrix

Similar to the answer given by @jérôme-richard you cannot store the whole inverse matrix in your memory. Instead, you would have to write a function that generates one column of the inverse Hilbert matrix at a time, and then multiplies your right-hand side vector with this column. Doing that 1 million times (for each column) gives you the solution vector.
Late answer but hope it still helps!